# Does Grails use Spring Dependency Injection by default

Tags: spring, grails, dependencies, code-injection

An additional question: What is service layer in Grails app?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Grails uses Spring Dependency Injection by default. Grails is in fact Spring at the core of it all.

Your second question, "what is a service layer" is best described as singleton instances of classes that serve as a layer of abstraction and encapsulation of business logic.

Comment: Services [don't have to be singletons](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#8.2%20Scoped%20Services), though.

Comment: Rob Hruska: That is 100% accurate, they aren't required to be singletons. However, they typically are.